# Datepicker set today's day as a default

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, set, default

So I have a datepicker and when I select a day, the day of the week is inserted into another input.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
onSelect: function(){
        var seldate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = seldate.getUTCDay();
        var weekday=new Array();
            weekday[0]="Maandag";
            weekday[1]="Dinsdag";
            weekday[2]="Woensdag";
            weekday[3]="Donderdag";
            weekday[4]="Vrijdag";
            weekday[5]="Zaterdag";
            weekday[6]="Zondag";
        var dayOfWeek = weekday[day];
        $('#DagWeek').val(dayOfWeek);
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine. But I wanted to set today's date + day as default before they select anything.
So I did this for the date:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
var dag = myDate.getDate();
if(dag < 10) dag = "0" + dag;
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
var vandaag = dag + '-' + month + '-' + myDate.getFullYear();
$("#datepicker").val(vandaag);
```

And it works too, but I want now to set today's day also as a default. So i tried to copy the same code 
as in the `onSelect` function but it didn't work. 
**The question is:** Can you tell me how to set this outside of the onSelect function? because I tried but it didn't work.
Just in case, this is what I tried:

```
var day = vandaag.getUTCDay();
alert("test? " + day);
var weekday=new Array();
    weekday[0]="Maandag";
    weekday[1]="Dinsdag";
    weekday[2]="Woensdag";
    weekday[3]="Donderdag";
    weekday[4]="Vrijdag";
    weekday[5]="Zaterdag";
    weekday[6]="Zondag";
var dayOfWeek = weekday[day];
$('#DagWeek').val(dayOfWeek);
```

**EDIT:** this is the HTML:

```
<td colspan="13">    
    <input type="text" id="DagWeek" name="DagNewSchema" size="12" readonly>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="NSchemaDatum" size="15" required>
</td>
```

As a result, this is what I get when I open the page for the first time:
[image]
And this is what I get when I actually select a date from the datepicker:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: @JohnDevelops Sure, I updated the question with the HTML + screenshots.

Comment: Just realised what you mean, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
function updateWeekDay($datepicker){
    var seldate = $datepicker.datepicker('getDate');
    var day = seldate.getUTCDay();
    var weekday=new Array();
        weekday[0]="Maandag";
        weekday[1]="Dinsdag";
        weekday[2]="Woensdag";
        weekday[3]="Donderdag";
        weekday[4]="Vrijdag";
        weekday[5]="Zaterdag";
        weekday[6]="Zondag";
    var dayOfWeek = weekday[day];
    $('#DagWeek').val(dayOfWeek);
};

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
onSelect: function(){
        updateWeekDay($(this));
    }
});

var myDate = new Date();
var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
var dag = myDate.getDate();
if(dag < 10) dag = "0" + dag;
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
var vandaag = dag + '-' + month + '-' + myDate.getFullYear();
$("#datepicker").val(vandaag);
updateWeekDay($("#datepicker"));
```

I might have some syntax errors as I typed this without testing but you get the idea, pull the code into a function an call it.